# Can we apply connection pooling to SQL native client

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, connection-pooling

I have a connection string in VBA (part of Excel sheet) which is connecting to SQL Server.

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;
```

It uses SQL Native client.

Can we apply connection pooling using `pooling='true'` in the connection string? If not how can we apply connection pooling?

Answer (score 0):

`SQL Native Client` does not include user-accessible functionality that already exists in the base MDAC **(Microsoft Data Access Components)** components, such as connection pooling, ADO support, memory management, or client-side cursor support. it uses MDAC to provide that functionality.

For more info go through this: [SQL Native Client](http://www.yaldex.com/sql_server/progsqlsvr-CHP-6-SECT-1.html)

**EDIT:**

There is an option of **[Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx)**.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Does it mean that connection pooling cannot be configured using SQL Native Client ?

Comment: I am not sure if MARS and connection pooling are same thing. As per my understanding MARS is multiple opened connection at the same time, while connection pooling is reusing the connection rather than closing /opening each time. In my case, connection is opened/closed for every query. Here MARS is not required. Connection pooling is required to take care of it automatically, otherwise i have to modify legacy methods to use same connection.